# how to access shared memory in .net application running on windows 7

Tags: c++

I am working on .net platform and using C++ to write my application. When I am using the following code to create a global shared memory to store some value in windows XP, it is perfectly working but on using it in Windows 7, it is giving error so I applied security attributes also but still it is giving permission specific error.

```
//Global declaration

TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyObject");

bool CreateDACL(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *sa)
{
    wchar_t *sdd = L"D:P(A;OICI;GA;;;SY)(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)(A;OICI;GRGW;;;IU)";
    return ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor((LPCSTR)sdd, SDDL_REVISION_1, &sa->lpSecurityDescriptor, NULL) == TRUE;
}

void CreateShareMemory()
{

HANDLE hMapFile =NULL;    // Create handle

    // Check if already created
    hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(
                   FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS,   // read/write access
                   FALSE,                 // do not inherit the name
                   szName);               // name of mapping object 

    // If not created, then create
    if(hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
        CreateDACL(&sa);

        hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                     INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                     &sa,                    // default security 
                     PAGE_READWRITE|SEC_COMMIT,          // read/write access
                     0,                       // max. object size 
                     256,                // buffer size  
                     szName);                 // name of mapping object

        int i=GetLastError();       // Here it is giving error no 5
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the error message  or error code?  What's the the usage scenario?  Is the producer and consumer using the same account?

Comment: Casting strings with (LPCSTR) *never* works, that's as wise as not checking the return value of a winapi function.  It just shuts up the compiler telling you that you are doing it wrong, it doesn't stop you from doing it wrong.  SDDL is a nasty rabbit hole as well, focus on making this work without hacking security.  Don't run programs elevated, don't try to break the WinRT sandbox.

Comment: It is giving error code 5, i.e. "Access is denied" and yes producer and consumer are using the same account.

Answer (score 2):

An ordinary user **cannot** create file mappings in the Global Namespace since [Session 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx) separation (and XP SP2 it looks like) without the [`SeCreateGlobalPrivilege`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) privilege.

Please read the documentation for the [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which mentions this explicitly:

> Creating a file mapping object in the global namespace from a session other than session zero requires the SeCreateGlobalPrivilege privilege. For more information, see Kernel Object Namespaces.

Your process is not running as a system service in session 0, and so cannot create a global file mapping without obtaining this privilege. The easiest way to obtain this privilege is to run the process with elevated privileges.

A possible alternative (untested, guesstimation based on information from a wide variety of unconfirmed sources) is to try to find the file mapping in the session's namespace by using the `Session\(number)\(name)`. If you open up the permissions on the mapping enough, it should be accessible by the other process.