# Shared memory on PC in windows 7 with ERROR 5

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, shared-memory

I've been trying to use shared memory on PC in windows 7 and get the common ERROR 5 (ACCESS DENIED)

I have searched the web for an answer, and I've found a lot of them and tried to implement all suggestions made to others with the same problem but It doesn't work! I have even tried to set privileges programatically but all in vain, because I did still get the ERROR 5.

Then I tried to change the Global\ to Local\ and that did work, but then I couldn't read it from the other process so I have changed it all back to Global\ and now I'm in the ERROR 5 scenario again.

```
   TCHAR szName[]=TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

   hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
                 INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
                 NULL,                    // default security
                 PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
                 0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
                 BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
                 szName);                 // name of mapping object

   if (hMapFile == NULL)
   {
    if (GetLastError() == 5)
     MessageBoxA(NULL,"5","ERROR 5",MB_OK);
    if (GetLastError() == 2)
     MessageBoxA(NULL,"2","ERROR 2",MB_OK);
    else if (GetLastError() == 183)
     MessageBoxA(NULL,"183","ERROR 183",MB_OK);
    else
     MessageBoxA(NULL,"just NULL","just NULL",MB_OK);
   }
```

What I'm trying to do; from the same .dll create a shared memory if it doesn't exist, and if it does already exist just read it (from the other process). The dlls are started from a host application where I can start multiple instances of the same .dll for testing. Then all of those dlls should be able to share the same buffer/array (it's a double*)

The thing is that I am lost here, don't know what thread to pull. Do I need to set privileges or not and if so, how do I do that. Because the code fragments I have found and tried while searching arn't working for me.

The closest question I have found here is [how to access shared memory in .net application running on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440893/how-to-access-shared-memory-in-net-application-running-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Regards, Morgan

Comment: But why do you prefix you name?

Comment: @manuell What do you mean with prefixed name? Where do I have a prefix?

Comment: `Global` is a prefix. Used when you want a shared memory reachable from multiple Windows sessions. Just drop it if it's not the case.